# Access Main thread data from the Background thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I´m using a backgroundworker to handle processing of data while the user is still free to for instance click another button that aborts the process.
However, the code in backgroundworker requires several pieces of data, for instance it needs to know whether a radio button is checked.

Is there a way to access data in another thread from the background thread? Or should I create global variables that hold this information?

```
Public Class Test
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Button1.Content = "Working..."
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        If RadioButton1.IsChecked Then
           MsgBox("It works")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: do you mean data or UI controls?  If/when the button or something is clicked you can abort the worker from the UI thread and pass data it needs like a boolean in the `DoWorkEventArgs`

Comment: Do you only need to know the state of the RadioButton when the BackgroundWorker **starts**?...or do you need to check the state **continuously** as it processes (and change what is happening, maybe in a loop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the RadioButton checked state to the RunWorkerAsync method like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(RadioButton1.Checked)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim checked As Boolean = CBool(e.Argument)
    If checked Then
        MessageBox.Show("It works")
    End If
End Sub
```

Let me know if you need to be checking the RadioButton **continuously** from inside a loop, as that would be different.